# Why does the height of the content area of an inline element larger than the value specified by font-size?

Tags: font-size

In a document like:

```
    <p class="wrapper">
        <span class="ref">
        <span class="text">English</span>
    </p>
```

the following rules are applied:

```
    .wrapper {
      background:green;
      position:relative;
      padding-left:20px;
      font-family:Times;
    }
    .text {
      line-height:1;
      background:blue;
      font-size:80px;
    }
    .ref {
      position:absolute;
      left:5px;
      width:10px;
      height:80px;
      background:black;
    }
```

In Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.79) or IE9, the background of the span element containing 'English' seems to have a height larger than font-size, yet in Firefox (13.0.1) the height equals font-size. ([See the output](http://jsbin.com/eputun/7/))

Can anybody explain this?

I thought the height of the content area would have the same value as specified by font-size.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a diagram showing the various reference lines available when rendering text:

[image: From WHATWG]

As you can see, there are many choices. It seems like Firefox is using a different baseline than Chrome/IE when rendering.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems to me that the em square used in Chrome is larger than that in Firefox, thus resulting a larger background area. Does the position of the aligned baseline affect the background area size (or height here)?